# MongoDb MapReduce creating bottleneck for Database queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mapreduce

In my project, I am using mongodb MapReduce for data aggregation and some heavy calculations on the aggregated results in Finalize function.

**Issue faced:**
If any MR job is in process than somehow for all the users the number of database requests / queries is getting limited to 2 - 3 per client. Any extra db query request (from the same client) is not entertained and user gets stuck. 
If any other user sends a http request or db query request (single OR max 2 -3 db requests) to node server it works fine. So it implies that my node loop is not blocked. Note that I am using only single node process (clusters are not yet used).

After the MR job completes, everything works fine and the pending database queries returns successfully.

To ensure that nothing is wrong with my project, I created a simple node project without express and mongoose and run a similar test on it. Issue was easily reproducible in that as well.

Any reason why this is happening ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you outputting to a collection here? And specifically using "merge" or "reduce"?

Comment: How come you have time to fix your typing mistakes but not the time to answer a simple question?

Comment: I am using "Output to a Collection" using Replace action. And nonAtomic doesn't work with Replace action.

Comment: What about "jsMode"? Are you setting that?

Comment: Tried with jsMode = true as well. But no help.